# What happens with Luke's hand?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-empire-strikes-back

In the end of *Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back*, Luke gets a bionic hand that looks perfectly like a normal human hand:
[image: Luke's bionic hand in The Empire Strikes Back]

But, as seen on *The Force Awakens* cinematic trailers, Luke's hand looks very robotic:
[image: Luke's hand in The Force Awakens]

Are there any clues as to what happens with his hand between *Return of the Jedi* and *The Force Awakens*?

Comment: I don't think there's canon to make an answer to this question yet.  But I can think of possible reasons: 1. Some prosthetic wearers have multiple prosthetics which have different purposes.  Some are more aesthetic, more realistic looking, and some sacrifice realism for function.  2.  Prosthetic wearers will get new prosthetics, and possibly upgrade over time.  3.  It's the same prosthetic, just minus the skin.  4.  Luke is in his steam punk phase. ;)

Comment: @DaG - agreed...

Comment: Out of universe - so we know it's Luke Skywalker under the cloak :)

Answer (score 1):

He use to have it gloved. Maybe, I believe, it's a reminder of how easy it can be to be persuaded to be turned to the dark side being his father to had a prosthetic mechanical hand. I believe it helps him maintain a firm grasp to the Force.